# Reddit API only returning one post

Tags: node.js, api, reddit

I am trying to get all of the links in a subreddit using the API, but it is only returning one url. Here is the code I have:

```
var request = require('request');
webpage = 'http://www.reddit.com/r/AmazonUnder5/top.json?limit=100';

//login
request.post('http://www.reddit.com/api/login',{form:{api_type:'json', passwd:'password', rem:true, user:'username'}});

//get urls
request({uri : webpage, json:true, headers:{useragent: 'mybot v. 0.0.1'}}, function(error, response, body) {
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        for(var key in body.data.children) {
            var url = body.data.children[key].data.url;
            console.log(url);
        }

    }
});
```

When I visit the json link in my browser, it returns all 100 posts.

Answer (score 2):

Thats because only 1 exists in the top

http://www.reddit.com/r/AmazonUnder5/top

You could use hot instead

http://www.reddit.com/r/AmazonUnder5/hot.json

Also, you don't need to log in to do public get requests

Edit: You are getting so few results because you are not logged in properly

When logging in, use the

```
"op" => "login"
```

Parameter and test what cookies and data is returned.

I also recommend using the ssl login url since that works for me

```
https://ssl.reddit.com/api/login/
```

Comment: I see more than one link. When I visit this page in my browser, 100 links show up: http://www.reddit.com/r/AmazonUnder5/top.json?limit=100